# How divide 2d array into 1d array by one statement?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = {5,7,8,9};
int[][] array2d ={a,b};
```

I can divide array2d into 2 1d array by:

```
int[] A = new int[array2d[0].length];
int[] B = new int[array2d[1].length];
for(int i = 0; i < array2d.lenght; i++){
   A[i] = array2d[i][0];
   B[i] = array2d[i][1];
}
```

but can it be done by one statement?

For example if I have:

```
int[][] array2dx = new int[2][1000];
```

I can do easy:

```
int[] Ax = array2dx[0];
int[] Bx = array2dy[1];
```

So I am look for something similar (dividing into 2 arrays) for `array int[1000][2];`

Comment: Yea, thats not going to happen.

Comment: Your original code looks pretty flawed to me - aside from anything else, that *is* an `int[2][]`... which is precisely the version you know how to deal with. It's really unclear what you're trying to do. It doesn't help that your sample input isn't rectangular, either.

Comment: Even if he got them in the same length, he wants in a single statement, I don't know of a way to transpose a 2D array in a single statement. unless that statement is a method call to transpose :)

Answer (score 1):

> but can it be done by one statement?

Not with any built-in methods that I'm aware of. It sounds like you basically want to write a transpose method though:

```
 static int[][] transpose(int[][] input) {
     // TODO: Validation. Detect empty and non-rectangular arrays.
     int[][] ret = new int[input[0].length][];
     for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = new int[input.length];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; i < ret.length; j++) {
             ret[j][i] = input[i][j];
         }
     }
     return ret;
 }
```

Once you've transposed an `int[1000][2]` into an `int[2][1000]` you can get the two `int[1000]` arrays out simply, as you've already shown.

Comment: I don't want transpose a array. I was thinking that is some trike way. e.g.: int[] X = array2d[][0].

Comment: @user1461568: It sounds like transposing an array is *exactly* what you want. You want to go from an `int[1000][2]` to two `int[1000]` - which is equivalent to wanting an `int[2][1000]`, i.e. transposition.